# What does "block not encountered" mean in a user profile?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, user-accounts, spam

I found a user who wrote two different spam posts which were flagged as spam, and got automatically deleted. Looking at the user profile, I read the following:

> blocked from asking             yes (block not encountered)

> [image: screenshot]

What does "block not encountered" mean?

Comment: Just a guess, based on the meaning of "encountered": perhaps the user is banned from asking, but has not yet tried to post something after the ban, so they have not yet "encountered" it.

Comment: That message could be reworded to make it more apparent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means exactly what it says.

There is a block in place (for asking in this case but it could be for answering) but the user hasn't tried to post a question (or answer) since the block was applied.

This means that the user isn't aware of the block.

However, they should be aware they were approaching the block as there is a warning message presented to the user when they get close.

Answer (score 5):

It means that the user is blocked from asking, but they have not yet loaded the "Ask Question" page and attempted to ask a question (i.e. they haven't "encountered" the ban yet and don't know that they're blocked).

Answer (score 3):

The user was blocked from an action, but since then has not tried to perform the blocked action, i.e. he is probably not yet aware of the block.